# Why are my Windows VMs now giving me NS_ERROR_FAILURE on startup since I upgraded VirtualBox to 5.1.20?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, gentoo

For some reason I cannot figure out (as I have been adjusting my VM settings to try and make this error go away, with no success) my Windows 7 and 10 VMs are failing to launch giving the error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows <NO>.

The VM session was aborted.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: SessionMachine
Interface: ISession {7844aa05-b02e-4cdd-a04f-ade4a762e6b7}
```

where `<NO>` is 7 for Win7 and 10 for Win10. Despite this my BSD, FreeDOS, Linux, Icaros, OpenIndiana and ReactOS VMs are starting fine. I have tried following this answer on Ask Ubuntu as close as I can (as I think VirtualBox has switched from using `xml` files to using `vbox` files for storing configuration settings) https://askubuntu.com/a/223763. In other words I removed my `.vbox` files for both Windows 7 and 10 VMs and moved `.vbox-prev` to `.vbox`. I have also tried rebooting after the upgrade from VirtualBox 5.1.18 to 5.1.20. If relevant my host OS is Gentoo Linux.

Here is my `.vbox` file for Windows 10 if relevant:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application
** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect.
** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes.
-->
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.15-linux">
  <Machine uuid="{25213a44-d63b-477e-a203-59635452c435}" name="Windows 10" OSType="Windows10_64" currentSnapshot="{67db068f-7287-4317-876b-b28a93a67d49}" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2017-04-21T16:56:07Z" aborted="true">
    <MediaRegistry>
      <HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{e1dde417-5c02-461f-8bb1-167cd1fc6155}" location="Windows 10.vdi" format="VDI" type="Normal">
          <HardDisk uuid="{b7e09ac5-2e76-44ea-85d1-f06f4539ef71}" location="Snapshots/{b7e09ac5-2e76-44ea-85d1-f06f4539ef71}.vdi" format="VDI"/>
        </HardDisk>
      </HardDisks>
    </MediaRegistry>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastCloseAction" value="PowerOff"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastGuestSizeHint" value="1600,795"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="0,23,640,480,max"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RestrictedRuntimeDevicesMenuActions" value="HardDrives"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RestrictedRuntimeMachineMenuActions" value="SaveState,PowerOff"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/ScaleFactor" value="1"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/ShowMiniToolBar" value="false"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/StatusBar/IndicatorOrder" value="HardDisks,OpticalDisks,FloppyDisks,Network,USB,SharedFolders,Display,VideoCapture,Features,Mouse,Keyboard"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <Snapshot uuid="{67db068f-7287-4317-876b-b28a93a67d49}" name="Snapshot 1" timeStamp="2017-02-24T11:04:25Z">
      <Hardware>
        <CPU>
          <PAE enabled="false"/>
          <LongMode enabled="true"/>
          <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="false"/>
        </CPU>
        <Memory RAMSize="4096"/>
        <HID Pointing="USBTablet"/>
        <Paravirt provider="Default"/>
        <Boot>
          <Order position="1" device="Floppy"/>
          <Order position="2" device="DVD"/>
          <Order position="3" device="HardDisk"/>
          <Order position="4" device="Network"/>
        </Boot>
        <Display VRAMSize="128"/>
        <RemoteDisplay enabled="false"/>
        <BIOS>
          <IOAPIC enabled="true"/>
        </BIOS>
        <USB>
          <Controllers>
            <Controller name="OHCI" type="OHCI"/>
          </Controllers>
        </USB>
        <Network>
          <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027BC7597" cable="true" type="82540EM">
            <NAT/>
          </Adapter>
          <Adapter slot="1" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
          <Adapter slot="2" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
          <Adapter slot="3" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
          <Adapter slot="4" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
          <Adapter slot="5" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
          <Adapter slot="6" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
          <Adapter slot="7" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        </Network>
        <LPT>
          <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="7"/>
        </LPT>
        <AudioAdapter controller="HDA" driver="ALSA" enabled="true"/>
        <Clipboard mode="Bidirectional"/>
        <DragAndDrop mode="Bidirectional"/>
        <GuestProperties>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxControl.exe" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1487831742829894000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxCredProv.dll" value="-" timestamp="1487831744274180000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxDisp.dll" value="-" timestamp="1487831742830753000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxGINA.dll" value="-" timestamp="1487831744274045000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxGuest.sys" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1487831746441185000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxHook.dll" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1487831742830648000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxMRXNP.dll" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1487831744273852000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxMouse.sys" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1487831746441474000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGL.dll" value="-" timestamp="1487831744275106000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLarrayspu.dll" value="-" timestamp="1487831744274402000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLcrutil.dll" value="-" timestamp="1487831744274571000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLerrorspu.dll" value="-" timestamp="1487831744274708000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLfeedbackspu.dll" value="-" timestamp="1487831744275013000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLpackspu.dll" value="-" timestamp="1487831744274821000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLpassthroughspu.dll" value="-" timestamp="1487831744274917000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxSF.sys" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1487831746441767000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxService.exe" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1487831743683193000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxTray.exe" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1487831743682974000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxVideo.sys" value="-" timestamp="1487831746441894000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/HostVerLastChecked" value="5.1.14" timestamp="1487831838478188000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/InstallDir" value="C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox Guest Additions" timestamp="1487831742828693000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Revision" value="112924" timestamp="1487831742828608000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Version" value="5.1.14" timestamp="1487831742828329000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VersionExt" value="5.1.14" timestamp="1487831742828545000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/MAC" value="080027BC7597" timestamp="1487831746445655000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/Status" value="Up" timestamp="1487831746445600000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/Broadcast" value="255.255.255.255" timestamp="1487831746445479000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP" value="10.0.2.15" timestamp="1487831746445410000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/Netmask" value="255.255.255.0" timestamp="1487831746445529000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/Count" value="1" timestamp="1487845608970464000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Product" value="Windows 10" timestamp="1487831742825086000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Release" value="10.0.14393" timestamp="1487831742826066000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="en_US" timestamp="1487845616040441000" flags=""/>
        </GuestProperties>
      </Hardware>
      <StorageControllers>
        <StorageController name="SATA" type="AHCI" PortCount="3" useHostIOCache="false" Bootable="true" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">
          <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" hotpluggable="false" port="0" device="0">
            <Image uuid="{e1dde417-5c02-461f-8bb1-167cd1fc6155}"/>
          </AttachedDevice>
          <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" hotpluggable="false" port="1" device="0"/>
        </StorageController>
      </StorageControllers>
    </Snapshot>
    <Hardware>
      <CPU count="3">
        <PAE enabled="false"/>
        <LongMode enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="false"/>
      </CPU>
      <Memory RAMSize="8192"/>
      <HID Pointing="USBTablet"/>
      <Paravirt provider="Default"/>
      <Boot>
        <Order position="1" device="Floppy"/>
        <Order position="2" device="DVD"/>
        <Order position="3" device="HardDisk"/>
        <Order position="4" device="Network"/>
      </Boot>
      <Display VRAMSize="128" accelerate3D="true"/>
      <RemoteDisplay enabled="false">
        <VRDEProperties>
          <Property name="TCP/Ports" value="3389"/>
        </VRDEProperties>
      </RemoteDisplay>
      <BIOS>
        <IOAPIC enabled="true"/>
      </BIOS>
      <USB>
        <Controllers>
          <Controller name="OHCI" type="OHCI"/>
        </Controllers>
      </USB>
      <Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027BC7597" cable="true" type="82540EM">
          <NAT/>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="1" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="2" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="3" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="4" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="5" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="6" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="7" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
      </Network>
      <LPT>
        <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="7"/>
      </LPT>
      <AudioAdapter controller="HDA" driver="ALSA" enabled="true"/>
      <SharedFolders>
        <SharedFolder name="Programs" hostPath="/home/fusion809/Programs" writable="true" autoMount="true"/>
        <SharedFolder name="Documents" hostPath="/home/fusion809/Documents" writable="true" autoMount="true"/>
      </SharedFolders>
      <Clipboard mode="Bidirectional"/>
      <DragAndDrop mode="Bidirectional"/>
      <GuestProperties>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxControl.exe" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1492704560791453000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxCredProv.dll" value="-" timestamp="1492704560794626000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxDisp.dll" value="-" timestamp="1492704560792313000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxGINA.dll" value="-" timestamp="1492704560794535000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxGuest.sys" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1492704560795853000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxHook.dll" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1492704560792200000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxMRXNP.dll" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1492704560794427000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxMouse.sys" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1492704560796087000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGL.dll" value="-" timestamp="1492704560795257000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLarrayspu.dll" value="-" timestamp="1492704560794758000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLcrutil.dll" value="-" timestamp="1492704560794847000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLerrorspu.dll" value="-" timestamp="1492704560794930000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLfeedbackspu.dll" value="-" timestamp="1492704560795177000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLpackspu.dll" value="-" timestamp="1492704560795014000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLpassthroughspu.dll" value="-" timestamp="1492704560795097000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxSF.sys" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1492704560796309000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxService.exe" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1492704560793480000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxTray.exe" value="5.1.14r112924" timestamp="1492704560793367000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxVideo.sys" value="-" timestamp="1492704560796407000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/HostVerLastChecked" value="5.1.20" timestamp="1492704701391273000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/InstallDir" value="C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox Guest Additions" timestamp="1492704560790219000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Revision" value="112924" timestamp="1492704560790140000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Version" value="5.1.14" timestamp="1492704560788816000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VersionExt" value="5.1.14" timestamp="1492704560789204000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/MAC" value="080027BC7597" timestamp="1492704560799558000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/Status" value="Up" timestamp="1492704560799509000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/Broadcast" value="255.255.255.255" timestamp="1492704560799413000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP" value="10.0.2.15" timestamp="1492704560799350000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/Netmask" value="255.255.255.0" timestamp="1492704560799461000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/Count" value="1" timestamp="1492705372643822000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Product" value="Windows 10" timestamp="1492704560787466000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Release" value="10.0.14393" timestamp="1492704560788182000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="en_US" timestamp="1492711972365764000" flags=""/>
      </GuestProperties>
    </Hardware>
    <StorageControllers>
      <StorageController name="SATA" type="AHCI" PortCount="3" useHostIOCache="false" Bootable="true" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">
        <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" hotpluggable="false" port="0" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{b7e09ac5-2e76-44ea-85d1-f06f4539ef71}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
        <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" hotpluggable="false" port="1" device="0"/>
      </StorageController>
    </StorageControllers>
    <Groups>
      <Group name="/Windows NT"/>
    </Groups>
  </Machine>
</VirtualBox>
```

Turns out this is a bug as downgrading to 5.1.18 fixing the error perfectly. I have reported this bug at the Gentoo Bugzilla https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=616238.

EDIT: Starting from the command-line gave a no more verbose output. Namely starting with:

```
VBoxManage startvm "Windows 10" --type headless
```

fails with the error:

```
Waiting for VM "Windows 10" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: The VM session was aborted
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface ISession
```

Comment: Gentoo has no such file (/etc/init.d/vboxdrv, the original question comment was deleted). That's what the `app-emulation/virtualbox-modules` package is for (updating the modules, that is), which I upgraded when I upgraded `app-emulation/virtualbox` to 5.1.20.

Comment: Don't you get any other error from VirtualBox?

Comment: No other error at all! I wish I did get one as that way I could add it here, providings you's with more to go on, and to the Gentoo bug report I filed.

Comment: Every time I upgrade VirtualBox, I get similar errors but always end up noticing a more detailed message somewhere.

Comment: Where though? All other VMs are working fine and these two VMs give the exact error I copied to this question. Help me help you!

Comment: I think that starting the VM from the command line gives more details.

Comment: Gave it a go and it gave no more verbose output, refer to my question, I've updated it to include the details.